# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I have successfuly implemented Froala to angular using RequireJS, but there occurs 2 problems.

If i want to add another plugin of froala (let's say url input) it returns an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

Cannot get it, if the main plugin froala does not return any errors, why does froala plugins return since coding is the same?

main.js

```js
/*jshint unused: vars */
require.config({
  paths: {
    angular: '../../bower_components/angular/angular',
    'angular-animate': '../../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate',
    'angular-cookies': '../../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies',
    'angular-mocks': '../../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
    'angular-resource': '../../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource',
    'angular-route': '../../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route',
    'angular-sanitize': '../../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize',
    'angular-touch': '../../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch',
    'ui-router': '../../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min',
    jquery: '../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
    bootstrap: '../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap',
    'angular-ui-router': '../../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router',
    'froala-editor': '../../bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/froala_editor.min',
    'froala-pl': '../../bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/languages/pl',
    froala: '../../bower_components/angular-froala/src/angular-froala',
    'froala-sanitize': '../../bower_components/angular-froala/src/froala-sanitize',
    'froala_url': '../../bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/plugins/url.min'
  },
  shim: {
    angular: {
      exports: 'angular'
    },
    'froala-pl': [
      'froala-editor'
    ],
    froala: [
      'froala_url',
      'angular',
      'froala-pl',
      'froala-sanitize'
    ],
    'froala-sanitize': [
      'angular'
    ],
    'angular-route': [
      'angular'
    ],
    'angular-cookies': [
      'angular'
    ],
    'angular-sanitize': [
      'angular'
    ],
    'angular-resource': [
      'angular'
    ],
    'angular-animate': [
      'angular'
    ],
    'angular-touch': [
      'angular'
    ],
    'ui-router': [
      'angular'
    ],
    'angular-mocks': {
      deps: [
        'angular'
      ],
      exports: 'angular.mock'
    },
    bootstrap: [
      'jquery'
    ]
  },
  priority: [
    'angular'
  ],
  packages: [

  ]
});

//http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/guide/bootstrap#overview_deferred-bootstrap
window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!';

require([
  'angular',
  'app',
  'angular-route',
  'angular-cookies',
  'angular-sanitize',
  'angular-resource',
  'angular-animate',
  'angular-touch',
  'ui-router',
  'jquery',
  'bootstrap',
  'froala',
  'froala_url'
], function(angular, app, ngRoutes, ngCookies, ngSanitize, ngResource, ngAnimate, ngTouch) {
  'use strict';
  /* jshint ignore:start */
  var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);
  /* jshint ignore:end */
  angular.element().ready(function() {
    angular.resumeBootstrap([app.name]);
  });
});
```

app.js

```js
/*jshint unused: vars */
define(['angular', 'controllers/main', 'controllers/admin', 'services/rest', 'services/auth', 'controllers/pages', 'controllers/dashboard']/*deps*/, function (angular, MainCtrl, LoginCtrl, RESTFactory, AuthFactory, PagesCtrl, DashboardCtrl)/*invoke*/ {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * @ngdoc overview
   * @name cmsApp
   * @description
   * # cmsApp
   *
   * Main module of the application.
   */
  return angular
    .module('cmsApp', 
      ['cmsApp.controllers.MainCtrl',
       'cmsApp.controllers.AdminCtrl',
       'cmsApp.services.REST',
       'cmsApp.services.Auth',
'cmsApp.controllers.PagesCtrl',
'cmsApp.controllers.DashboardCtrl',
/*angJSDeps*/
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.router',
    'froala'
  ])
    .config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

      $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'main'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
          url: '/dashboard',
          templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/index.html',
           resolve: { authenticate: authenticate },
          controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'dashboard'
        })
        .state('dashboard.subpage', {
          url: '/page/:id',
          templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/pages/edit.html',
          params: {
                    id: null
          }
        })
        .state('admin', {
          url: '/admin',
          templateUrl: 'views/admin.html',
          controller: 'AdminCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'admin'
        });


      function authenticate(Auth, $state, $timeout) {
        var Auth = Auth.isLogged();

        return Auth.then(function(response){
            var data = response.data;
                      if(data.logged_in == false)
                      {
                          $timeout(function(event) {
                              $state.go('admin');
                          }, 10);
                      } 
        });
      }

      
    });

});
```

fraola_url.min.js

```js
/*!
 * froala_editor v2.0.1 (https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)
 * License https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/terms
 * Copyright 2014-2015 Froala Labs
 */

! function(a) {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? module.exports = function(b, c) {
        return void 0 === c && (c = "undefined" != typeof window ? require("jquery") : require("jquery")(b)), a(c), c
    } : a(jQuery)
}(function(a) {
    "use strict";
    a.extend(a.FroalaEditor.DEFAULTS, {}), a.FroalaEditor.URLRegEx = /(\s|^|>)((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(:\d*)?(\/[^\s<]*)?)(\s|$|<)/gi, a.FroalaEditor.PLUGINS.url = function(b) {
        function c(d) {
            d.each(function() {
                if ("IFRAME" != this.tagName)
                    if (3 == this.nodeType) {
                        var d = this.textContent.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, "");
                        a.FroalaEditor.URLRegEx.test(d) && (a(this).before(d.replace(a.FroalaEditor.URLRegEx, '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>$7')), a(this).remove())
                    } else 1 == this.nodeType && ["A", "BUTTON", "TEXTAREA"].indexOf(this.tagName) < 0 && c(b.node.contents(this))
            })
        }

        function d() {
            b.events.on("paste.afterCleanup", function(b) {
                return a.FroalaEditor.URLRegEx.test(b) ? b.replace(a.FroalaEditor.URLRegEx, '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>$7') : void 0
            }), b.events.on("keyup", function(d) {
                var e = d.which;
                (e == a.FroalaEditor.KEYCODE.ENTER || e == a.FroalaEditor.KEYCODE.SPACE) && c(b.node.contents(b.$el.get(0)))
            }), b.events.on("keydown", function(c) {
                var d = c.which;
                if (d == a.FroalaEditor.KEYCODE.ENTER) {
                    var e = b.selection.element();
                    if (("A" == e.tagName || a(e).parents("a").length) && b.selection.info(e).atEnd) return c.stopImmediatePropagation(), "A" !== e.tagName && (e = a(e).parents("a")[0]), a(e).after("&nbsp;" + a.FroalaEditor.MARKERS), b.selection.restore(), !1
                }
            })
        }
        return {
            _init: d
        }
    }
});
```

Shims configuration

```js
'froala-editor': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'froala-sanitize': {
      deps: [
        'angular'
      ]
    },
    froala: {
      deps: [
        'angular',
        'froala-editor',
        'froala-pl',
        'froala-sanitize'
      ]
    },
    'colors': {
      deps: [
        'jquery',
        'froala-editor'
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the editor's archive for using it with RequireJS: https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/blob/master/html/require_js/index.html#L49

Comment: I tried it for single plugin, as for your hint too. Still not works, still the same error but i got a hint. I tried to replace "function" == typeof(...) from plugin with function of editor and...module error dissapered, but nothing affects to editor. Problem is with coded plugins, not with my configuration. I've added my shims at the end of my question.

Comment: Yes, indeed there is a problem with the plugins from bower when using with requireJS in v2.0.1. There will be a new release v2.0.2 shortly that will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

"bower angular-froala" automaticly install also "froala-wysiwyg-editor" with bad repo plugins, I had to replace whole plugins with sources from there: https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor.